# Convert rate from multiple type of currency to MYR by sql in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, currency, bq

I want to convert the total rate from multiple type of currency to myr as shown in this [table](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZMiuHwIDxY06Qdlc35zGsxtElMYcgrjh/view?usp=sharing).
I want to use sql in Bigquery to convert the amount from usd to myr.

Please help me for this question.

Thanks

Comment: Dear Dan, welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use case when expression to convert your currency by multiplying with appropriate conversion rate for MYR.

```
select (case when currency='USD' then amount*4.15 when currency ='MYR' then amount end) Amount from yourtable
```